# How do I write a Joi schema to check for username and password in the body of a request or authorization in the header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have inherited an older API that used POST requests for everything and specified username and password in the body. I am working on modernizing the API bit by bit but initially I need to keep existing functionality. I am adding the capability to provide an authorization header and want to build a standard validation function that will check if either the username and password exist in the body or the authorization exists in the header.

In addition, in some cases there will be an extra required field in the body regardless of which authorization values are passed.

I am using Joi to do this validation and have ran through multiple iterations using either `.or`, `Joi.alternatives()` or `.when()`.

Joi.alternatives approach:

```
const schema = Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required()
    })
  }), Joi.object({
    headers: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required()
    })
  }).unknown()
  );
```

.when approach 1:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().when('headers.authorization', {
        is: Joi.exist(),
        then: Joi.forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.required()
      }),
      password: Joi.string().when('headers.authorization', {
        is: Joi.exist(),
        then: Joi.forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.required()
      })
    }),
    headers: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required()
    }).unknown()
  });
```

.when approach 2:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string(),
      password: Joi.string()
    }),
    headers: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string()
    }).unknown()
  }).when(Joi.object({ headers: { authorization: Joi.not().exist() } }), {
    then: Joi.object({
      body: Joi.object({
        username: Joi.required(),
        password: Joi.required()
      })
    })
  }).when(Joi.object({
    body: {
      username: Joi.not().exist(),
      password: Joi.not().exist()
    }
  }), {
    then: Joi.object({
      headers: Joi.object({
        authorization: Joi.required()
      })
    })
  });
```

.or approach1:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required()
    }),
    headers: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required()
    }).unknown()
  }).or('body', 'headers.authorization');
```

.or approach2:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required()
    }),
    headers: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required()
    }).unknown()
  }).or(Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required()
    })
  }), 'headers.authorization');
```

Each of these has been tried with different methods of calling such as:
`const {error, value} = schema.validate(request);`
`const {error, value} = schema.validate({body: request.body, headers: request.headers});`

```
const {body, headers} = request;
const {error, value} = schema.validate({body, headers});
```